# Consume Secure Kafka from databricks spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to consume from a secure Kafka Topic ( using SASL_PLAINTEXT, ScramLogin Method).

Spark Version 2.3.1
Scala 2.11
Kafka latest

I am using the Spark Structured stream to construct the stream. For this purpose I imported the library : spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1

This imports the older version (0.10.0.1) of the kafka-clients.jar.

Below is my client.jaas :

```
KafkaClient {
 org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
 mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
 security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
 client.id="*****"
 username="****"
 password="*****";
};
```

I am using the ScramLoginModule and the kafka-clients jar specified above, does not even have this jar. So, I added the later version of the kafka Clients jar file kafka-clients-1.1.1-cp1.jar

In my notebook, I have the following code :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spark.implicits._

val kafkaSource = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",   "host:port")   
    .option("subscribe", "topic")    
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") 
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1)

  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism","SCRAM-SHA-512")
  .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_PLAINTEXT")
  .load()


val kafkaStream = kafkaSource.
  select(
    $"key" cast "string",   // deserialize keys
    $"value" cast "string", // deserialize values
    $"topic",
    $"partition",
    $"offset",
    $"timestamp",
    $"timestampType")

import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter

kafkaStream.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {

  override def process(row: Row): Unit = {
    println("Processing : " + row.mkString(","))
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}

  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    true
  }
}).start().awaitTermination()
```

From the driver logs, I can see that the I am able to connect fine .

```
18/09/05 13:09:46 INFO AbstractLogin: Successfully logged in.
18/09/05 13:09:46 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values:
```

But after this, nothing happens !! It just gets stuck after printing hte following lines :

```
18/09/05 13:09:47 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0.1
18/09/05 13:09:47 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : a7a17cdec9eaa6c5
```

The above version of Kafka is also very confusing as I am nowhere using this version (Although this was the version of the kafka client that gets imported automatically when I add the spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1 library. But I had chosen to exclude the kafka-clients jar when I did that import).  The kafka clients that I am using as I said is of a higher version and so is the kafka cluster to which i am connecting.

To replicate this, I ran the same code on a spark cluster running on my own laptop, and everything works fine, where I am able to consume and print the kafka messages.

Anyone who has experienced similar issue, please advise !!